# How to comprehensively check for unsaved work?

Tags: git

I'm working with a large number of git repositories that aren't terribly small. Disk space is an issue so I need to remove some repos I'm not using to make room for others.

How do I comprehensively check for unsaved work before `rm -rf project/`?

I've googled around and haven't found anything that's a direct answer. I have cobbled together this alias that so far seems sufficient, if a bit ugly in output.

```
    unsaved = "!f() {  \
                echo '=====[ Unpushed commits ]==================================================';  \
                git branch -v;  \
                echo '=====[ Uncommited work ]===================================================';  \
                git status;  \
                echo '=====[ Uncommited stashes ]================================================';  \
                git stash list;  \
                echo '=====[ Unpushed tags ]=====================================================';  \
                git push --tags --dry-run;  \
               }; f"
```

This checks in all the corners I know of for work that would be lost if the repo is deleted. Pretty self-explanatory, but a couple of notes: LFS changes should be revealed by the `git status` command; changes in submodules should similarly be revealed. Orphaned commits are not handled, would be lost on repo deletion, but that's okay for my current purposes. I have an alias for finding all orphans if I change my mind later.

Have I missed anything?

I just remembered worktrees are a thing. I don't know how to handle that right now since I've never worked with them. A quick google doesn't help. Are worktree changes reflected in `git status`?

Comment: To answer your last question, changes in a worktree look just like changes on a traditional branch.  The main difference is that all worktrees for a given repo are linked together, so the list of branches, stashes, tags, etc are all shared.  So if one of your repos has associated worktrees, you may see more results with your `unsaved` command than you would normally.

Comment: Are any of your "large number of git repositories" cloned from the same source?  If so, worktrees would help with your disk space problem.

Comment: @0x5453 Are they cloned from the same source? No, but they should have been. I've inherited something of a cut n paste spaghetti factory which I don't have resources to deduplicate properly right now.

Answer (score 0):

shallow clone can save a lot of space and avoid to have to rm

```
 git clone --depth 1 somewhere/repo.git
```

Documentation:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of shallow copies; Github Universe 2020's [Optimize your monorepo experience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcqLV1lU408) was really insightful. They don't help me in this situation unfortunately.